# Why is the coefficient of change in x on change in y smaller than coefficient of x on y?

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients

I'm running a regression of firm productivity (output per worker) on income by looking at how wages change when employees switch to a more or less productive firm. When I regress log of firm productivity `va` on log of wages `y`, the coefficient is ~0.23. However, when I regress the *change* in firm productivity `dva` on the *change* in wages `dy` the coefficient is ~0.08. I'm at a loss for why the difference between the two is so big.

```
=========================================
                 Dependent variable:     
             ----------------------------
                   dy             y      
-----------------------------------------
female         -0.016***      -0.197***  
                (0.004)        (0.005)   

education       0.005***      0.071***   
                (0.001)        (0.001)   

age             -0.026**      0.093***   
                (0.011)        (0.014)   

age^2            0.001*       -0.002***  
                (0.0003)      (0.0004)   

age^3           -0.00000     0.00001***  
               (0.00000)      (0.00000)  

dva             0.076***                 
                (0.003)                  

va                            0.233***   
                               (0.004)   

Constant        0.397***      -1.427***  
                (0.136)        (0.179)   

-----------------------------------------
Observations     23,144        23,144    
Adjusted R2      0.040          0.463    
=========================================
```

I can understand that other coefficients like age and the female indicator would be bigger, because `y` is much larger than `dy`, but since `y`:`va` and `dy`:`dva` are of similar magnitude relative to one another, I don't see where the change is coming from. Is it a statistical thing? Would you see this for any regression of x on y versus $\Delta$x on $\Delta$y? Or is it more specific to my case of wages and I should look for omitted variables or something?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You have levels model on log vs. difference model. Why should the coefficients be similar?

Comment: You're right, I wasn't fully thinking through what my models were doing. My thought process was that there is a relationship between a worker's income and the productivity of the firm—causal or not—which holds as people move firms. Shouldn't those same factors be influencing the change in productivity?

But I think I understand now that's not the case: with a differences model, those factors are subtracted off on each other, allowing me to better isolate the relationship between productivity and income.

Also, you taught me some good vocabulary for the models, cheers for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By including a constant in your differenced model, you are implicitly including a linear time trend which is not in your original levels model:

$$y_{i,t}  - y_{i,t-1}=(\alpha_i + \beta x_{i,t} + \gamma t)-(a_i+\beta +x_{i,t-1}+\gamma (t+1))=\gamma + \beta (x_{i,t} - x_{i,t-1})$$

Try running the dy regression without the constant or add time as regressor in the y model.

This may not fix the difference, but at least it will be more of an apples to apples comparison.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the constant, it didn't change the coefficients much, but writing out the equations behind the regression like that helped to clarify what I'm actually measuring here.

Comment: @Joey Even without the constant, they could be calculating different things.  For example, you probably have an omitted regressor in your model, time-invariant ability. If more able people sort into more productive firms because they like being around other able people, the coefficient on firm productivity will pick up some of that and be biased upward. When you difference out the ability with the FD transformation, you are remedying that bias, so it makes sense that the effect declines. It is even possible for the effect to switch signs after doing this, not just change in magnitude.